# Timeout in XmlDocument.CreateDocumentType method

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I am building a custom XML document.

The following code takes upwards of 30 seconds to execute (see comments) Why?

```
var doc = new XmlDocument(); 
doc.AppendChild(doc.CreateXmlDeclaration("1.0", "utf-8", null));

// hangs on next line - doc.CreateDocumentType()
var xmlDocType = doc.CreateDocumentType(
            "svg"
            , "-//W3C//DTD SVG 20001102//EN"
            , "http://www.w3.org/TR/2000/CR-SVG-20001102/DTD/svg-20001102.dtd"
            , null);

doc.AppendChild(xmlDocType);
```

When this takes over 30 seconds, I get the following exception:

***`System.Net.WebException:`***

```
"The underlying connection was closed: The connection was closed unexpectedly."
```

***`Exception Stack Trace:`***

```
at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetNonFileStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
at System.Xml.XmlDownloadManager.GetStream(Uri uri, ICredentials credentials, IWebProxy proxy, RequestCachePolicy cachePolicy)
at System.Xml.XmlUrlResolver.GetEntity(Uri absoluteUri, String role, Type ofObjectToReturn)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.OpenAndPush(Uri uri)
at System.Xml.XmlTextReaderImpl.PushExternalEntityOrSubset(String publicId, String systemId, String
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Probably because your resolver is trying to fetch the specified DTD from www.w3.org.

They're not serving up the DTDs directly any more due to heavy traffic (see [this link](http://www.w3.org/blog/systeam/2008/02/08/w3c_s_excessive_dtd_traffic) for info).

You need to download the DTDs from their W3C web site, cache them locally and have your resolver map the specified URL to your locally cached copy.